# send Container.ItemIndex onserverclick

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to send the  Container.itemindex, of a repeater, to server side using html button

I tried

```
<button   id="tdb1" commandname="ok"  onserverclick=go(Eval('<%#Container.ItemIndex)%>') >update</button>
```

I alse tried

```
<button   id="tdb1" commandname="ok"  onserverclick=go('<%#String.Format(".tdb_{0}", Container.ItemIndex)%>') >updtae</button>
```

I know I can get easliy the itemindex with

`<asp:button commandname="somename">`

But it important to me to use simple html button and not server one(i have a style to the text of the button,but in asp:button the text is part of the label>

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Go with the server control and find another way to format your controls not the other way around.

Comment: :) if I don't have a choise I go with your Suggestion but you know it's the "switcher" of jquery(the built  template css for the all site)it really amazing solution for those who want to change css in easliy ,but when it come to change it ,this is a problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Use an ASP.NET button and set the ItemIndex in the command argument.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>' OnCommand="Button1_Command" ...>
```

And in your click event, append the format:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string format = Strng.Format(".tdb_{0}", e.CommandArgument);  
}
```